# ¿Cómo regresar de una activity2 a la activity1 al presionar back?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy usando un `navigationView` pero al presionar hacia atrás se me regresa a la secuencia de botones apretados por ejemplo si presiono activity 1,2,3,4 y luego 2,4,3, al regresar se me regresa en 3,4,2 y luego al 4,3,2,1, quiero que en vez de eso simplemente regrese al activity 1 sin importar en cual esté, este código uso para el `navigationView`:

```
bottomNavigationViewEx.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.mapa:
                        Intent mapa = new Intent(Go.this, Mapa.class);
                        startActivity(mapa);
                        break;

                    case R.id.taxi:
                        Intent taxi = new Intent(Go.this, Taxi.class);
                        startActivity(taxi);
                        break;

                    case R.id.help:
                        Intent help = new Intent(Go.this, Help.class);
                        startActivity(help);
                        break;

                    case R.id.go:
                        break;

                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Pedro, tu Activity principal como se llama? Go?

Comment: No, estoy en la activity go, quiero regresar a la activity mapa dando back, sin tener que regresar a la activity help o taxi por ejemplo, al colocar finish me manda a la main activity, no quiero eso.

Comment: En este caso cuando realices un `Intent` desde la `Activity` mapa no finalices la `Activity` pero cuando realices un Intent desde otra `Activity`, finaliza usando `finish()`!

Comment: Si, muchas gracias me resolvió el problema

Comment: El único problema que quedó es que si estoy en el activity mapa, al presionar back, se regresa el activity mapa de nuevo, ¿Si me explico? y ya al estar ahi si quisiera salir de la aplicación

Comment: Por ejemplo estoy en mapa, abro go, vuelvo a abrir mapa y al dar atrás, se vuelve a abrir mapa y al darle atras ahi se se sale.

Comment: "abro go, vuelvo a abrir mapa",  define <activity android:name=".mapa"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"> o FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP agrego actualización

Comment: Ya quedó listo gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para eso tienes que finializar las actividades una vez saltes a la otra con el metodo `finish()` para que no se almacenen en la pila de navegacion.

Por ejemplo:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Help.this, Activity2.class));
finish(); // eliminamos la actividad actual de la pila de navegacion
```

Asi siempre que navegues, no se "agregara" al boton back.

Comment: pero me regresa a al activity main, quiero regresar al activity mapa

Answer (score 0):

**Si no te encuentras en la `Activity` pricipal, cuando realices un Intent para abrir otra Activity, usa `finish()` para terminarla**, para que únicamente 
permanezca MainActivity, por ejemplo.

```
    Intent taxi = new Intent(Go.this, Taxi.class);
    startActivity(taxi);
    finish(); //Finaliza!
```

Cuando te encuentres en tu `Activity` principal (Activity 1) no realices la terminación de la misma mediante `finish()`.

---

Si únicamente deseas tener una instancia de tu Activity principal puedes agregar esta propiedad en el AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".mapa"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

o definir a tu Intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: quiero regresar al mapa, porque mi activity principal es otra

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontre la solución agregando este código a los intent de mapa,

startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Mapa.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
                        finish();

Así cada vez que le des a mapa se eliminan las activitys almacenadas y regresa a la de mapa sin necesidad de que se cree una nueva de mapa.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes `Activity1` por un lado y `ActivityMapa` por otro.

Si quieres regresar de `ActivityMapa` a `Activity1`  cuando presionas el botón de retroceso, puedes indicar en el `Manifest` que el padre de `ActivityMapa` es `Activity1`, usando `parentActivityName`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MapaActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity1">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.paquete.Activity1" />
    </activity>
```

He puesto sólo las partes relevantes del XML, las otras que tengas las dejas como están.

Tienes que cambiar `com.example.paquete` por tus propios datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes configurar el onClick del onBackpressed y mediante un Intent mandarlo al activity 1 que tengas, en este caso "Mapa" si no he entendido mal.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent volver = new Intent(Go.this, Mapa.class);
                        startActivity(volver);   
     finish();            

}
```